# Changing position of UIViews when viewcontroller is dismissed

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a ViewController which presents another view controller. When the second one is dismissed, I have a boolean in the first controller, isFromSecondView, set to true. So when my first ViewController is visible again, viewWillAppear is called and I can move around some views within the controller from there. This method works fine and the viewWillAppear method can decide if it came from the second view controller or not. But I cannot move the views inside the controller around, even though it is being called. Is this method the way I should be doing this, or is there another way to move views around when the second controller is dismissed?

edit, added the view moving method:

```
- (void)moveViews
{
    NSLog(@"moving view");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         self.view.center = CGPointMake(160, 250);
                         //self.tableView.center = CGPointMake(160, -100);
                         self.addView.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
}
```

Comment: Could you post some code about the `UIView`'s switching?

Comment: Added the method that gets called from viewWillAppear above.

Comment: Are `view` and `addView` `nil`?

Answer (score 0):

`dismissViewControllerAnimated` has a completion handler you can use. This will execute your animation code as soon as the controller is done dismissing. Of course, you'll need to make changes to handler this being executed in another controller if that's where you use this.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"moving view");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                     animations:^{
                         self.view.center = CGPointMake(160, 250);
                         //self.tableView.center = CGPointMake(160, -100);
                         self.addView.center = CGPointMake(160, 240);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
}
```

Comment: I already tried that, the code is run, but nothing happens. I think because the views are nil for some reason? Any idea how I can fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the viewWillLayoutSubviews (in your controller) to layout your views whenever needed.

Example:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
  [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
  // self.oneView.center = ...
  // self.anotherView.center = ...
}
```